# Eclipse project shows an unnecessary project folder that cannot be removed

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a Java project in Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2018-12 (4.10.0) built with Maven.

For some reason the folder `src/test` shows in Project Explorer as a "project folder" (by that I mean a Eclipse project folder, not a file system folder), besides being shown in the project as a *source folder* as well. That seems unnecessary and anomalous. For example, the same does not happen with `src/main`, which appears as a source folder only:

[image]

If I try to delete the project folder `src/test`, Eclipse warns me that it contains source folders which will be deleted along with it. I actually tried it anyway once: made a copy of the files, deleted the `src/test` project folder, and then replaced the files in the disk, but when I do that, the project folder just pops back.

Why is this happening and how can I clean it up?

Comment: Please show you pom file cause your layout looks a little bit unusual ...

Comment: That you have `src/main` as a source folder makes no sense, since `src/main/java` is nested and also a source folder. In contrast, the fact that `src` is displayed as a regular folder makes sense, because otherwise `src` would not be selectable (e.g. to search in it) and e.g. it would not be possible to create a subfolder via the right-click menu.

Comment: Eclipse becomes confused once in a while.  Check out from source control in a fresh workspace and see if the problem persists.  Be certain you do not have eclipse configuration files in source control.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen _"Eclipse becomes confused once in a while."_ ← I have never experienced or heard of Eclipse making a regular folder a source folder for no reason. Has this been reported as a bug? Please link the bug you are referring to.

Comment: @howlger you are 100% sure this is still present in a fresh workspace?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen You claimed that from time to time Eclipse converts a regular folder into a source folder for no reason. I asked you for a link to the report of this bug you are talking about. As I said before, I have neither faced nor heard of such a bug, so I don't know if switching to a fresh workspace can be used as a workaround for this bug.

Comment: @howlger No, I did not claim such a thing.  I said that occasionally Eclipse becomes confused - I've seen it happen way back with e.g. merge conflicts in configuration files which were checked into source control, and then we are in "undefined behavior"-land.  Question was if problem could be **reproduced** in a fresh - hopefully non-polluted - workspace.  If not, well, problem solved, if yes, well time for a bug report.    So, just ask for a Minimal, Reproducible example next time you need to triage a report and then see where it leads the reporter.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Be more specific. What do you mean by _occasionally_ and _becomes confused_. What problem are you talking about that can be "solved" by a fresh workspace? Please note, showing the `src` folder without its `main` subfolder is the expected behavior here since `src` is a regular folder and `src/main` is a source folder. Sure, `src/main` should not be a source folder here, but this is not caused by an "occasionally confused Eclipse".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Checking out from source control into a fresh workspace does not help here: see my answer below. Please help make Eclipse better by making sure that the bugs you are facing are reported. It is a hoax that Eclipse becomes confused once in a while. Please do not spread this hoax.

Comment: @howlger I recently was told that a bug I reported more than ten years ago had been fixed which was nice.  Is m2e able to emulate the Maven feature of separate classpaths for "main" and "test" these days?  If not, I think I'd rather have that fixed first.

Comment: @howlger True.  My eclipse gold badge is not quite as telling as it used to be, as it is almost five years ago I was properly introduced to IntelliJ.  Do you have  URL to the classpath separation issue so I can have a closer look?  Also thank you for reminding me to remove "eclipse" from my watched tags. Enjoy.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen _Enjoy_!? I'm sick of these comments by IntelliJ fanboys spreading FUD about Eclipse. What makes you say these false claims about Eclipse over and over again without knowing Eclipse for years?

Comment: @howlger I have an eclipse gold badge. Let me know when you do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `src` with its subfolder `test` is shown for reasons

There are regular and source folders. For faster access **source folders** are displayed **compacted on the first level** instead of in the regular folder tree. In your case, there are five source folders `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java`, `src/test/resources` and - probably by mistake (see below) - `src/main` which are not shown in the regular folder tree, but on the first level.

In contrast, `src` and its subfolder `test` are **regular folders** and therefore are shown (even if they are empty except for the source folders) in the regular **folder tree**. They are shown **so they can be selected and the right-click menu can be shown** containing commands (which might be contributed by additional installed plug-ins) related to selected folders only. Selecting all source folders contained in `src` is not the same as selecting the `src` folder, for instance when doing a file search on the selected folders, a `.gitignore` file in the `src` folder would otherwise be missed.

#### `src/main` should not be a source folder

To have `src/main` and its subfolder `src/main/java` as source folders do not make sense since they are nested. In your case, it is a Maven project so you can **right-click the project folder** and choose ***Maven > Update Projects...*** to derive the source vs. regular folders settings from the `pom.xml` file and overwrite the settings made manually. These settings are stored in the `.classpath` file. In Maven projects the `.classpath` file can be derived from the `pom.xml` file and therefore it is recommende not be shared or versioned.